# How to extend bash-completion with the already exist completion in another file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-completion, completion

For example, there is bash-completion for rar on linux, I want to extend, make more completions for the same command - rar, maybe for my own filename extension, but I don't want to touch the already existing completion script, how to start it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The base support is usally in `/etc/bash_completion` and details in the directory `/etc/bash_completion.d`

For more information, see:

[An introduction to bash completion: part 1](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1) for general knowledge
[An introduction to bash completion: part 2](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) for details on scripts in `/etc/bash_completion.d`